# Backbone.js suitable for mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-website, backbone.js

I've been looking into backbone.js lately and like both the philosophy and the execution a great deal.  Is anyone using Backbone on HTML5 IOS interfaces?

What are your experiences with this approach?

Comment: If it's not up for discussion, don't discuss it. :)

Comment: Valid point.  Edited for brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used JQuery Mobile UI with backbone.js. The problem is they both have their own hashchange router. If you can live without the backbone router or figure a way to cut out the JQuery one then it works out well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'm sure you just saved me an hour of future head scratching.  I poked into the code a little bit- it's a real mess.  Basically you have to choose between respecting the UI state or the data state of the application, right?  Meshing the two would be a nightmare.

Comment: Actually since then I've dropped JQuery mobile totally and rolled my own CSS and just use vanilla jquery and a custom backbone page layout util. I've pasted the code here I use, sans css, https://gist.github.com/1027122

Answer (score 3):

I think Basecamp from 37 Signals is the best example of a complex app using backbone (and other awesome frameworks): http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2761-launch-basecamp-mobile#comment_63518

I do not have first hand comments on this unfortunately.

Comment: "Basecamp Mobile is written in CoffeeScript using our in-house Cinco mobile framework, which ties together Backbone.js, Zepto, the Eco templating language, and Stitch."  You can't develop on Rails and not respect the work the 37signals team does, I can't wait to see if they are as effective at mobile as they are with web.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a project on github ( https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router ) that provides a router for jquery mobile.

It's perfect with backbone.js, it's almost a replacement for its controller, so we can finally use the full backbone.js potential in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the [trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) (a cross-platform framework) demo apps make use of `backbone.js`

Comment: Yep, we've blogged a tutorial on how to use backbone.js for mobile web apps and with hybrid frameworks like Trigger.io: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/03/02/how-to-build-fast-html5-mobile-apps-using-backbone-js-zepto-js-and-trigger-io/

Answer (score 0):

I used Backbone.JS + jQueryMobile on iOS/Android. Works pretty fine. Check out
[my blog post](http://vmirgorod.name/blog/building-iosandroid-mobile-app-using-backbonejs-jquerymobile-and-html):

Comment: Is Backbone.history.start(); working for you?